# Multiple level friendship

Tags: c++, friend

In code below:

```
class B {
    int x;
    int y;
};

class A {
    friend class Other;
    friend class A;
    int a;
     B* b;
public:
    A(){ b = new B();}
};

struct Other {
    A a;
    void foo() {
        std::cout << a.b->x;  // error
    }
};

int main() {
    Other oth;
    oth.foo();
}
```

The indicated line fails with:

```
t.cpp:22:19: error: 'x' is a private member of 'B'
std::cout << a.b->x;
                  ^
t.cpp:7:5: note: implicitly declared private here
int x;
```

Why friendship is not working when referring from class member to other class member?

Comment: Well, `Other` isn't a `friend` of `class B` hence the private `B::x` can't be accessed there.

Comment: If an answer worked for you, [mark it as accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). If no one did, add a comment asking for clarification or corrections (if needed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
std::cout << a.b->x;
```

involves accessing a private member of `A` (`b`) and a private member of `B` (`x`) within class `Other`. While `A` gave access privileges to `Other`, `B` did not, hence the error. If you want this to work, you'll need to add:

```
class B {
    friend class Other;
};
```

---

Side-note, this declaration is meaningless:

```
class A {
    friend class A;
};
```

A class already has access to its own private members. So calling it its own friend is redundant.

Answer (score 2):

Although this is a weird use of `friend`s, I assume it is for learning purposes. That said, you should fix your `friends` definition like this:

```
class B{
    friend class Other; // Because you access private member x from Other::foo()
    int x;
    int y;
};

class A{
    friend class Other; // Because you access private member b from Other::foo()
    int a;
    B* b;
public:
    A(){ b = new B();}
};

struct Other{
    A a;
    void foo(){
      // Access A's private member b
      // Access B's private member x
      std::cout << a.b->x; 
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class B{
friend class Other;
int x;
int y;
};
```

Comment: Code-only answers aren't helpful. You should articulate *why* OP should try this. What does what you did work while what OP did errors?